# How does a url gets to know which server it needs to reach?

Tags: networking, dns

I was wandering what happens when say we type a url like httt://www.mydomain.com? How does it comes to know where to go to lookout the pages of mydomain.com? How does all this happens?

Answer (score 0):

http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/791/DNS+Explained

When a user types in a web address like example.com, or when any software other than a browser attempts to access a domain (such as an email address @example.com), the first step is for the request to go to a DNS server.  DNS servers come essentially preprogrammed so your computer can locate them... the default is set by your Internet Service Provider, though some advanced users prefer to use a different service like opendns.

DNS servers essentially act much like an index of a book.  They return the IP address of the web server hosting the website (or mail, or other service, etc.).  These domain / IP address pairs are configured via the domain's registrar (such as GoDaddy.com), where the website owner can program in the IP address of their web server.

Hope that helps.